# Reopening of my question

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reopen-closed

I kindly ask if it is possible for [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923098/how-does-mega-co-nzs-download-manager-work) to be reopened.

It got closed for being apparently off-topic, however, I do not see how it is off topic -- Every part of the question conforms to the rules and topics on SO. In the meantime, it has also gathered upvotes, which, at least to me, seem a clear indication that, apart from people who do have the reputation to close questions at their personal whim, others agree that this question is indeed on topic. An explanation was also not offered as to why exactly it is considered off topic.

I do not have the reputation points to do it myself, so I have to rely on the help of the community here.

Direct permalink to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923098/how-does-mega-co-nzs-download-manager-work

Comment: We aren't tech support, and we aren't a documentation repository. Look through the relevant documentation and/or ask the company that created the download manager in question.

Comment: Re: *"apparently, closing is considered a perfectly acceptable substitute on SO"*. It is not the responsibility of Stack Overflow users to be familiar with the entire network. It is consider rude to migrate questions to a site if you are not familiar with their policies, and relatively few Stack Overflow users are familiar with many other sites. It is therefore not reasonable to expect questions to be migrated instead of closed, even if there is another suitable place on the network.

Comment: How your question falls into HTML5 and javascript tags ?

Comment: Upvotes do not a question make good.  Personal whim does not a good question get closed.  Explanations are not always in the offing, rules not always understood.  Not all questions have a home. Stay patient grasshopper, you will see.

Comment: Well, now the question got outright deleted. Is that the way to go on SO? Very professional.

Comment: It has been deleted because it belongs absolutely nowhere on the Stack Exchange network of sites.

Answer (score 11):

Take away the product name. Take away the screenshot. The question is essentially "How do I download files in the background?" Nothing more. **This question would be closed.** People would rightfully ask "what have you tried?" We want more than screenshots and product names and "please help me reverse engineer this, thank you."

Answer (score 5):

Since I voted to delete...my reasons:

- No clear steps to even see the behavior. I went to the site in question...do I need to signup? am I using the right browser? There might have been a salvageable question if you had attempted to look at the HTTP traffic, provide a snippet of script, research background download techniques, etc.
- Snide comments how "users aren't don't know the answer, so they close" and "SO really hates certain questions." That doesn't sound like an attitude willing to refine the question into something *much* more specific and meaningful.

As it stands, it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not directly related to programming . The how to guides are usually provided on the product sites and in their forums . Stackoverflow doesnt allow questions of these types . You can read more about asking questions on About us and FAQ page .

The About us page states - Dont ask :

```
Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)
Product or service recommendations or comparisons
Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.
Anything not directly related to writing computer programs
```

Your question falls into the last category and needed to be closed .